# How to find the implementation contract address in a proxy contract?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

There's an Upgradeable proxy pattern that allows upgrading a smart contract by pointing an implementation address in a proxy contract to a new address of upgraded contract.

Is there a way to find address of the implementation contract? When I'm looking at the proxy code I see the following:

```
// This is the keccak-256 hash of "eip1967.proxy.rollback" subtracted by 1
bytes32 private constant _ROLLBACK_SLOT = 0x64_bytes_string;

/**
    * @dev Storage slot with the address of the current implementation.
    * This is the keccak-256 hash of "eip1967.proxy.implementation" subtracted by 1, and is
    * validated in the constructor.
    */
bytes32 internal constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x64_bytes_string;
```

Nothing in the code seems revealing the address of the implementation contract.

Comment: That looks to be incomplete (like its a template).  The proxy contract I am looking at contains `bytes32 internal constant _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc;`

Answer (score 0):

Some block explorers (such as Etherscan) now provide a way to navigate directly to the proxy contract implementation from the proxy contract's deployment address.

Answer (score 0):

The `_IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` is the memory in proxy contract, where the address of the implementation is saved. To retrieve current implementation contract address you can read that storage:

```js
let proxyContract = "0x_YOUR_PROXY_CONTRACT";
let storagePosition = "0x360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc";
let address = await web3Client.eth.getStorageAt(proxyContract, storagePosition);
```

Comment: how do you get the storagePosition?

Comment: From the source code. This is the constant, a big number to prevent the storage collisions. `0x360....` is the result of `keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation") - 1`

Comment: so you'd find this in the source code of the proxy contract on etherscan?

Comment: Yes, but this is a **common** PROXY pattern. Take a look into proxy detection code here: [dequanto/BlockChainExplorerFactory.ts#L85](https://github.com/0xweb-org/dequanto/blob/5e8a0c346b8af5af636ad42a08297add227fd6c0/src/BlockchainExplorer/BlockChainExplorerFactory.ts#L85) Here we check different proxy implementations. Also you can look into [openzeppelin/proxy](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy) to read about different proxy patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar question on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103143/how-do-i-get-the-implementation-contract-address-from-the-proxy-contract-address
and if there is no implementation().call() function, there is a guide how to get _IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT constant from the proxy contract.